# How do I reset the handle to 0?

Tags: c, xlsx

I am trying to use xlsxio library to write strings to cells but the handler doesn't reset after iteration. I need to reset the handle to run other calls to this function.

```
#include "include/xlsxio_write.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_LEN 1000
#define filename "report.xlsx"

xlsxiowriter handle;

void xlsx(xlsxiowriter hand, int row, int col, char* data) {
    int i, s;
    for (i = 1; i < (row + 1); i++) {
        if (i == row) {
            for (s = 1; s < (col + 1); s++) { // check for column
                if (s == col) {
                    xlsxiowrite_add_column(hand, data, 10);
                } else {
                    xlsxiowrite_add_column(hand, NULL, 5); // if not row, write empty string in row (skip it)
                }
            }
        } else {
            xlsxiowrite_add_cell_string(hand, ""); // if not row, write empty string in row (skip it)
            xlsxiowrite_next_row(hand);
        }
    }
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    handle = xlsxiowrite_open(filename, "example");

    xlsx(handle, 5, 2, "hello");
    xlsx(handle, 5, 3, "there");
    xlsx(handle, 8, 8, "mate");

    xlsxiowrite_close(handle); //close xlsx file
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with this API, but maybe you should use `xlsxiowrite_open` and `xlsxiowrite_close` in `xlsx(...)` (obtaining a new handle in each call).

Comment: It seems like this library doesn't append things, if I close it it will just write instead of append new items. Yes this would be a nice solution but it doesn't seem like this lib works that way sadly.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to use xlsxio library to write strings to cells but the handler doesn't reset after iteration. I need to reset the handle to run other calls to this function.

You appear to be out of luck.  As far as I can tell, [xlsxio](https://github.com/brechtsanders/xlsxio/tree/master) supports only sequential writing, not random access.  This lightweight API expects you to write data left to right, top to bottom.  You cannot skip cells or rows (other than by writing empty ones), or go back to previously-written rows or previous cells of the same row.